# How to extract href, title, and text data from an <a> tag with a specific class value from scraped html?

Tags: php, regex, dom, preg-match-all, domparser

I've this regex expression for the `preg_match_all()` that matches correctly on regex101.com but not on my code.

The html element I'm trying to parse looks like this:

`<a class="profile-link" href="CompanyProfile.aspx?PID=4813&amp;country=211&amp;practicearea=0&amp;pagenum=" title="1-844-Iran-Law">Amin Alemohammad</a>`

Which is found int the whole html curl result. Each block has the following eg.:

```
<li style="opacity: 1;">
   <a class="profile-link" href="CompanyProfile.aspx?PID=4813&amp;country=211&amp;practicearea=0&amp;pagenum=" title="1-844-Iran-Law">Amin Alemohammad</a>
   <!--<a class="profile-link" href="javascript:void(0)" title="1-844-Iran-Law">Amin Alemohammad</a>-->
   <img src="/Images/Uploaded/Photos/4813_1844IranLaw.png" style="max-width:140px; max-height:140px">
   <div class="results-profile">
      <h2>Amin Alemohammad</h2>
      <p><strong>Firm:</strong> 1-844-Iran-Law <br> <strong>Country:</strong> USA</p>
   <p class="blue"><strong>Practice Area:</strong> Iranian Desk</p>
   <ul>
      <li class="tel-icon" style="opacity: 1;">Tel: +1-202-465-8692</li>
      <li class="fax-icon" style="opacity: 1;">Fax: +1-202-776-0136</li>
      <li class="email-icon">Email: <a style="position:relative; z-index:9999;" href="mailto:amin@1844iranlaw.com">amin@1844iranlaw.com</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div><!-- results profile -->
      <img class="practice-logo" src="/Images/Uploaded/Logos/4813_1844IranLaw.png" style="max-width:185px; max-height:70px;">
      <a class="results-btn contact-btn" href="CompanyProfile.aspx?PID=4813&amp;country=211&amp;practicearea=0&amp;pagenum=" title="View Full Profile">VIEW FULL PROFILE</a>
      <!--<a class="results-btn contact-btn" href="CompanyProfile.aspx?PID=4813&country=211&practicearea=0&pagenum=" title="1-844-Iran-Law">CONTACT</a>-->
      <a class="results-btn website-btn" href="http://www.1844iranlaw.com" title="www.1844iranlaw.com">VIEW WEBSITE</a>
   </li>
</li>
```

The regex result

```
Group 1.    54-58   `4813` // company profile
Group 2.    71-74   `211` // country id
Group 3.    92-93   `0` // practice area
Group 5.    115-129 `1-844-Iran-Law` // company name
Group 6.    131-147 `Amin Alemohammad` // Person's name
```

What I have is:

```
preg_match_all('/<a class="profile-link" href="CompanyProfile\.aspx\?PID=(.*?)&amp;country=([0-9]{1,}?)&amp;practicearea=([0-9]{1,10}?)&amp;pagenum=\?" title="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/', $result, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
dd($match);
```

which returns

```
array:6 [▼
   0 => []
   1 => []
   2 => []
   3 => []
   4 => []
   5 => []
]
```

The number of matches are correct -> 5 matches in the string pattern but what I can't figure out is why it's returning empty values.

Thanks for any help in advance as I've tried so many approaches but for not the correct one or seeing what am I missing.

Comment: There's a `\?` in your regex which doesn't belong in there, after `pagenum=`. When you remove it works fine.

`/<a class="profile-link" href="CompanyProfile\.aspx\?PID=(.*?)&amp;country=([0-9]{1,}?)&amp;practicearea=([0-9]{1,10}?)&amp;pagenum=\?" title="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/` should be
`/<a class="profile-link" href="CompanyProfile\.aspx\?PID=(.*?)&amp;country=([0-9]{1,}?)&amp;practicearea=([0-9]{1,10}?)&amp;pagenum=" title="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/`

Comment: Still getting the same empty values in the array.

Comment: It works for me using the above regex and your sample result.

Comment: Picking just that block of code, yes, it works. But I'm getting the whole content from the `<body>(...)</body>` of the curl result. Probably something might be breaking it and returning empty values

Comment: I don't know what the whole content looks like, so I can't really help you debug it. Perhaps there are line feeds in the content in between `<a...>` and `</a>`? If so, you could add the [`s` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) at the end of the regex. Or try the DOMDocument answer. Regexes are [notoriously bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5024519) at parsing HTML.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Have to figure it out the best way preg_match_all or the DOMDocument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some time digging into the problem, analysing the whole html to be parsed by the `preg_match_all()` I just git it working by adding a couple of lines to replace the `\t \r \n` from the html since adding it to the regex didn't work.

So the solution wha to add the following two lines before the `preg_match_all()`:

```
(...)
$result = curl_exec($curl); // already there

$result = str_replace(["&amp;"], "&", $result); // new
$result = str_replace(["\t", "\r", "\n"], "", $result); // new
$regex = '/<a class="profile-link" href="CompanyProfile\.aspx\?PID=(.*?)&country=([0-9]{1,}?)&practicearea=([0-9]{1,}?)&pagenum=" title="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/s';

preg_match_all($regex, $result, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Then, instead of having in the link the `&amp;`I forced the `&` character in the regex. It's working like charm!

Than you all who have been there giving a hand!

Comment: You are parsing HTML so you should be using an html parser like DomDocument for reliability.  Instead of calling `str_replace()` twice, call it once and write an array of _search_ strings and an array of _replace_ strings.  That said, if your answer has resolved your issue, please award your answer the green tick so that this page is deemed resolved in the system.

Comment: Hi mickmackusa, thanks for the tips. When the answer was posted I wasn't still able to award the answer green tick. Thanks.

Comment: Is there only one profile-link class in the html? or are you possibly finding multiple matches in a single page?  (I'm going to post a clever new approach)

Comment: don't use str_replace, we have a proper function for decoding html, 
 it's called [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) - but yeah, don't use regex either, use a proper DOM parser.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regex you could use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

To get the values from the `href` attribute you could use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
$html = <<<HTML
<a class="profile-link" href="CompanyProfile.aspx?PID=4813&amp;country=211&amp;practicearea=0&amp;pagenum=" title="1-844-Iran-Law">Amin Alemohammad</a>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    if ($a->getAttribute('class') === 'profile-link') {
        $parts = explode('?', $a->getAttribute('href'), 2);
        parse_str($parts[1], $output);

        echo 'Title: ' . $a->getAttribute('title') . '<br>';
        echo 'Text: ' . $a->nodeValue . '<br>';
        echo 'PID: ' . $output['PID'];
        // etc..
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/iC8Gr)

Comment: When using `explode()` to cut a string in half, please write the `limit` value as `2`.  This ensures that `explode()` is never over performing, and it tells future developers that the intent of your code is to cut the string in half.  Win-Win.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you for the suggestion. Feel free to edit it!

Comment: Thanks The fourth bird. It looks much cleaner, less expensive and more efficient. I must admit I've not worked to much with DOMDocument so far but will invest some time on it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. You should also definitely look at the answer from @mickmackusa.

Answer (score 1):

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kfEl1))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$output = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//a[@class='profile-link']") as $node) {
    parse_str(parse_url($node->getAttribute('href'), PHP_URL_QUERY), $output);
    $output['title'] = $node->getAttribute('title');
    $output['text'] = $node->nodeValue;
}
var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'PID' => '4813',
  'country' => '211',
  'practicearea' => '0',
  'pagenum' => '',
  'title' => '1-844-Iran-Law',
  'text' => 'Amin Alemohammad',
)
```

I believe this leverages the full beauty of the php language with `DomDocument` with `Xpath` to reliably/directly target the qualifying tag/node, then `parse_url()` with `parse_str()` to eloquently convert the querystring data into the desired key-value pairs.

Now you'll have something stable with no hacky `str_replace()` calls or regex patterns.

Comment: thanks for using the proper functions for this, an XML parser to extract the url, parse_url to extract the query from the url, and parse_str to parse the query, you did it all **the way it should be done**, good job. :)

Comment: @McRui have I sufficiently answered your question?